# Convert to timestamp

Tags: oracle

I got a column with the following timestamp format currently stored as varchar2:

```
31DEC2019 13:20:51,847
```

I don't really recognize this format, and I have a hard time writing a mask that captures the values. I have tried using this, and variations of it:

```
'DDMONYYYY HH:MIN:SSFF3'
```

But no luck. Any ideas? My goal is to convert the column from varchar2, to timestamp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be the right format:

`'DDMONYYYY HH24:MI:SS,FF3'`

Here we have:

- `DD`: day
- `MON` month
- `YYYY` year
- `HH24`: hour in 24-hours format
- `MI`: MInutes
- `SS`: seconds
- `,`: the separator
- `FF3` milliseconds

This assumes that your strings represent timestamps in the language that your session is using; for example, say you have that value stored, if you work wiat a session in English language, everything works:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_language='English';

Session altered.

SQL> select to_timestamp('31DEC2019 13:20:51,847', 'DDMONYYYY HH24:MI:SS,FF3') as t from dual;

T
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
31-DEC-19 01.20.51.847000000 PM

1 row selected.
```

With the same data, a different session language can give errors:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_language='Italian';

Modificata sessione.

SQL> select to_timestamp('31DEC2019 13:20:51,847', 'DDMONYYYY HH24:MI:SS,FF3') as t from dual;
select to_timestamp('31DEC2019 13:20:51,847', 'DDMONYYYY HH24:MI:SS,FF3') as t from dual
                     *
ERRORE alla riga 1:
ORA-01843: mese non valido
```

This happens because, in the example, 'December' is 'Dicembre' in Italian, so the month part should be 'DIC' and not 'DEC'.

No matter the session language, if you know that data are stored in English, or whatever other language, you can force the usage of the needed language in the `to_timestamp` call:

```
SQL> select to_timestamp('31DEC2019 13:20:51,847', 'DDMONYYYY HH24:MI:SS,FF3', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = English') as t from dual;

T
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
31-DIC-19 01.20.51.847000000 PM

1 riga selezionata.
```

Comment: This seems to be more correct, thanks! It gives me an error though regarding "not a valid month" using that mask - even though all the month abbreviations are correct. Any ideas?

Comment: Just added some more details.

Comment: And that did the trick! Thank you, just learned a lot from that :)